# Curl failed with return code: 3221226356

Tags: curl, memory-management, tfs, release

I have a release that was working fine until a day ago.  Now I am seeing this error:

```
Curl failed with return code: 3221226356.
```

Curl Step1, and here is what I see in the log...
Channel failed to close: -34
curl failed with error: curl failed with return code: 3221226356

[image: Screenshot]

Comment: And this is from the log.

Comment: Channel failed to close: -34
100  8128    0     0    0  8128      0   8128 --:--:-- --:--:-- --:--:-- 16288
100  8128    0     0    0  8128      0   8128 --:--:-- --:--:-- --:--:--  8128
Connection #0 to host svdx-mlmweb left intact
##[debug]rc:3221226356
##[debug]success:false
##[error]curl failed with return code: 3221226356
##[debug]task result: Failed
##[error]curl failed with error: curl failed with return code: 3221226356

Comment: If you have more information (like your log), you should edit your question and add it there, instead of making a comment. Also you should provide more information about what (code) exactly is not working. An error code and a log is rarely enough to tell you where your problem lies.

Comment: Could you reproduce this issue continuously? If the release that was working fine before and suddenly not work. Then this maybe a network issue, have you double confirmed this? Also check if you build agent could connect  the URL to the location where you want to upload the files.

Comment: Yes, I can recreate.  This worked then suddenly it is not working.  One thing I noticed, If I pick an indivdual file it will transfer that fine, however using the wildcards it will fail after the first file.  I have been using the wild cards all along, and I have too many files to setup a seperate step for each individual file.